# @Test annotation not working junit 4

Tags: maven, junit4

I'am trying to test a class with Jnuit 4 in a maven project. The test runs successfully when I run it from my STS, but when I try to run it from maven command line, I get the following error:
**annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
    @Before**

Code under test is:

```
public class MyContollerTest{
 @Before
 public void setup(){
    System.out.println("This is MyControllerTest before..."); 
 }
    @Test
    public void testShouldTest(){
        System.out.println("This is MyControllerTest"); 
    }
    @After
    public void tearDown(){
        System.out.println("This is MyControllerTest after..."); 
    }
}
```

I'm using the Junit 4.8.1 as maven dependecy

I have checked my complience level is 1.6 and I'm using jdk 1.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add `maven-compiler-plugin` config in the `build` section of the `pom.xml`

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you set appropriate `source` and `target` of your `maven-compiler-plugin` [according to the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)?

Comment: @Boris/@Constantiner you are a star!!! I added maven-compiler-plugin and it worked like a charm :-) Thanks.

Comment: So you can accept one of the answers and/or vote up for both or an other :)